# Use JPA locks in web components

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, locking

I understood the principle of JPA locks (optimistic and pessimistic) but noticed that all locks you apply to an entitymanger, query etc. are always on the server side. All EJBs are located on the server and thus transactions used by them also are locked on the server.

Say, a costumer of your e-commerce website wants to change his data. The user is filling in his changes in the client (e.g. facelets) and then submits them by sending them to the server which then obtains a lock. But what if an admin has altered the costumers data between the initial read and before the lock-obtain? This would result in a dirty read

So how can I extend the locking mechanism to the web tier? 

 I didn't find an option on the web but without it the current locking API of JPA would be pretty useless, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid dirty reads, but without blocking the entities can make use of a feature of JPA called "Version Locking" which is to add an attribute to the entity class with his @Version.

Example simple:

```
@Entity
public class Persona implements Serializable {
  //... other properties

  @Version
  @Column(name="VERSION")
  private long version;

// getters and setters
}
```

Now if someone updates the data before you and then try to update the data, JPA Engine throw an exception indicating that someone else and update the information. This option prevents blockages that can cause poor performance of the entire application

Comment: Thanks but I'm familiar with the concept of optimistic locks. The thing is that JPA checks for changes at the end of each transaction. Well, this gives protection against dirty reads but only for the time of the transaction. This security is absent, if the client is making changes to data in his browser since there's no transaction making sure no one else is altering the same bit of data at the same time.